# Can an attacker force a browser to use quirks mode to render a page?

Tags: web-browser, vulnerability, html

During a pentest, I've found a potential vulnerability on a web page, but it can only be exploited in [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

The page starts with `<!doctype html>`, which [triggers standards mode](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/) so at first glance, it isn't exploitable.

Are there some techniques an attacker could use to force quirks mode, even when standards mode have been enforced with a standard doctype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potentially, yes. If the page supports being framed (that is, it does not have a prohibiting `X-Frame-Options` header, or similar), then you can frame it in a quirks-mode page, and at least some browsers (IE up to at least version 9, possibly IE11, possibly others) will use the same rendering mode for the parent page and its sub-pages. The normal render mode detection (based on doctype, etc.) will not be used on the framed pages.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in Firefox / Chrome, though. https://esnard.github.io/stackexchange/security/180335/top.html

Comment: Cool trick. I tried it in IE11 and messed with the document mode using the dev tools (don't have actual older IEs to test with handy, but it could be arranged). IE5 (Quirks): BackCompat [ BackCompat ]. IE7: CSS1Compat [ CSS1 Compat ]. IE8: same as IE7. IE9: Same as IE7. IE10: BackCompat [ CSS1Compat ]. IE11: Same as IE10. Now I'm really curious how the older browsers actually performed. But yeah, probably only older browsers will be affected.